# Как получить в виде текста содержимое document-fragment в JS

Tags: javascript

```
var myDocfragment = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document);
```

myDocfragment - является объектом типа - document-fragment. Как мне получить в виде текста все теги со значениями ? Хочу его передать сюда - document.write(...)

Вот мой код:

```
var res_xml = json2xml(o_rows, o_cols);
var xslStylesheet;
var myXMLHTTPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
myXMLHTTPRequest.open("GET", "xsl/rep_list.xsl", false);
myXMLHTTPRequest.send(null);


var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
xslStylesheet = myXMLHTTPRequest.responseXML;
xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslStylesheet);


var myDocFragment = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(res_xml, document);
var wnd_list=window.open("", "wnd_list");
wnd_list.document.body.appendChild(myDocFragment);
```

```js
function json2xml(obj_json, a_fields) {
    var doc = $.parseXML("<root/>");
    var xml = doc.getElementsByTagName("root")[0];
    var elem, a_cnt, s_row, s_str;
    var gr_rows= doc.createElement('rowset');
    for (key in obj_json) {
        if (obj_json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            el_row = doc.createElement('row');
            ochild=obj_json[key];
            for (key2 in ochild) {
                if ($.isEmptyObject(a_fields)) {
                    a_cnt=[0];
                }
                else {
                    a_cnt=$.grep(a_fields , function (element, index) { return element.field == key2; });
                }
                if (a_cnt.length>0){
                    elem = doc.createElement(key2);
                    s_str=ochild[key2];
                    $(elem).text(s_str);
                    el_row.appendChild(elem);
                }
            };
            gr_rows.appendChild(el_row);
        }
    }
    xml.appendChild(gr_rows);
    return xml;
}
```

Пример res_xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<rowset>
<row>
<recid>3</recid>
<date_reg>13.09.2016 17:20:48</date_reg>
<rep_type>Отчет по расходам на содержание жилья</rep_type>
<creator>Омаров Габит </creator>
<rep_stat>Создан</rep_stat>
</row>
</rowset>
<colset>
<col>Номер</col>
<col>Дата</col>
<col>Наименование</col>
<col>Автор</col>
<col>Статус</col>
</colset>
</root>
```

Пример rep_list.xsl:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
   <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
         <xsl:for-each select="root/colset/col">
            <th align="center"><xsl:value-of select="."/></th>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="root/rowset/row">
         <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
               <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Выложил демонстрацию:

1. Открыть ресурс https://demo.topksk.kz
2. Ввести:
   login: gabit.omarov@gmail.com
   pass: orapas$123
3. Вставить url: https://demo.topksk.kz/reports.html и нажать Enter.
4. "Тип заявки" - выбрать "Отчет по расходам на содержание жилья".
5. Нажать на кнопку - "Поиск"
6. В табличной части нажать на кнопку - "Вывод списка"

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46527/discussion-on-question-by-gabit-omarov-------doc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо этой строки:

```js
var myDocFragment = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(res_xml, document);
```

Поставил так:

```js
doc=$.parseXML(res_xml.outerHTML);
var myDocFragment = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(doc, document);
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` лучше не использовать в данном случае, так как фрагмент - это объект, при вставке которого в DOM, вставляется все его содержимое, без непосредственного элемента фрагмента.

Поэтому для вставки его содержимого на страницу, нужно использовать например [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), на том элементе куда необходимо вставить, либо [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).

Например:

```
var myDocfragment = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document);
document.body.appendChild(myDocfragment);
```

Comment: Я так попробовал. Проблема с отображением возникает в FireFox-е. Наверное из-за того что: У DocumentFragment нет обычных свойств DOM-узлов, таких как innerHTML, tagName и т.п. Это не узел

Мне надо получить содержимое myDocfragment с тэгами. Как это сделать ?

Comment: @GabitOmarov, DocumentFragment - не является узлом и в DOM не вставляется, вставляется только его содержимое, поэтому он не может служить причиной ошибки отображения в FireFox. Очевидно нужно просто проверить стили.

Comment: Стиль имеете введу XSL файл ? Я использую один и тот же файл для всех, он находиться на сервере приложения.

Comment: @GabitOmarov, я имею ввиду css - который отвечает за отображение. Если после вставки содержимого в элемент что-то показывается не так, значит ему не установлены нужные css-стили. Если ты все еще пытаешься использовать document.write - ничего не получится. Используй appendChild, или insertBefore, как я указал в ответе

Comment: вот мой код:  
[code]
var res_xml = json2xml(o_rows, o_cols);  
var xslStylesheet;  
var myXMLHTTPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();  
myXMLHTTPRequest.open("GET", "xsl/rep_list.xsl", false);  
myXMLHTTPRequest.send(null);  
  
var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();  
xslStylesheet = myXMLHTTPRequest.responseXML;  
xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslStylesheet);  
  
var myDocFragment = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(res_xml, document);  
var wnd_list=window.open("", "wnd_list");  
wnd_list.document.body.appendChild(myDocFragment); [/code]

Comment: @GabitOmarov, все необходимое должно быть непосредственно в вопросе

Comment: заново вопрос создать ?

Comment: @GabitOmarov, нет, отредактировать существующий, перейдя по этой ссылке: [edit]